# How to avoid long loading times with sql using delphi xe3

Tags: sql, delphi-xe3

At the moment i use delphi xe3 and an online database,
I use

```
db.active:=False;
DB.sql.text:='slect*from database';
db.active:=True;
```

to show and filter records, but when i get to about 1000 records in the database, it becomes very slow, is there a way to make the program usable while the db is being loaded,

kind of like facebook loads while you type, and shows records when they're found.

thank you

Answer (score 0):

Th problem is in * in your select, and ofc in amount of data. You must draw data as it goes from server. I don't know what components do you use so any information about it will be helpfull... In DevExpress's grid component there is property called "GridMode" for this.

Comment: well i use zeoslib to connect, and zquery to get the info from the tables, and then show them in a dbgrid